# How do i use a const method in a superclass

Tags: c++, constants

OK, I'm going to try this one more time. I am not an experienced C++ programmer, so I just need a little help with something. Here is some very simple code, which won't compile. What I want to know is, is it possible to define the getData() and size() methods, such that the code will compile? The error i get is:

error C2662: 'iContainer::getData' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const iContainer' to 'iContainer &'

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdint.h>

class   iContainer  {
public:
    virtual         const int       size()  = 0;
    virtual         const uint8_t * getData()   = 0;
    void    operator=(const iContainer &iC) { saveToEEPROM(iC.getData(), iC.size()); }

private:
    void    saveToEEPROM(uint8_t *pData, int size) {
        // Save the data to EEPROM. 
    }
};


class Timer : public iContainer {
public:
    Timer()  {
        pData.myData = 0;
    };
    Timer(uint8_t startHour) {
        pData.myData = startHour;
    }
    virtual const int size()  { return sizeof(pData); }
    virtual const uint8_t *getData()  { return (const uint8_t *)&pData; };
private:
    struct {
        uint8_t myData;
    }   pData;

}
```

Comment: /OT: Tip: `std::function` is very performance heavy (in both compilation and runtime). It shouldn't be used unless absolutely needed (you don't).

Comment: Please provide exact line which makes compiler unhappy and full compiler message. Your code snippet doesn't seem to show it.

Comment: @Rakete1111, no worse than virtual functions all over this code (same level). OP doesn't seem to care about performance at all.

Comment: @SergeyA Didn't know that virtual functions were *that* bad :) Yeah, a [mcve] would be nice, [it compiles fine here](https://ideone.com/KZArfm)

Comment: Refrain from prefixing identifiers with underscores.  This style is reserved for compilers and there is a possibility that your symbols may conflict.

Comment: FYI, all classes that inherit from `iContainer` will be affected by your suggested change.  Do you really want to do that?

Comment: In C++, you don't need to use `this->` to call class methods.  It wastes development time and may introduce typos.

Comment: The assignment operator should return a reference to the modified instance to allow for chaining, such as `x = y = z;`.

Comment: Nested structures or classes introduce complexity into your system.  Is there a need for the private structure in the `Timer` class?

Comment: Thank you all for your very instructive comments. As you can clearly see c++ is not my forte. But I really would like to know how to solve this. The example now shown is the code that fails to compile. @George, I'm sorry for upsetting your sensibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend refraining from placing assignment operators in superclasses (or parent classes).

There are 2 main issues here: 1) Slicing and 2) Polymorphism.

**Polymorphism**
Placing an assignment operator in a super class allows for:

```
class Fruit;
class Apple : public Fruit;
class Orange : public Fruit;
void Blender(Fruit * p_fruit)
(
  Apple a;
  Orange o;
  Fruit * ptr_o = &o;
  Fruit * ptr_a = &a;
  // This is syntactically allowed, but may not make sense.
  *p_fruit = *ptr_o;
  *p_fruit = *ptr_a;
  // This is also allowed:
  *ptr_o = *ptr_a;  // Assigning apples to oranges
}
```

The superclass cannot make any guarantees (contract) about the child classes.

**Slicing (, form of)**
The only guarantee when assigning members are the members in the superclass.  This is a form of slicing; only the superclass members are copied (assigned).

One could create a virtual assignment method, but again, the child has no idea if the parameter is to a cousin or a sibling (see Polymorphism above).

**Summary**
Don't place assignment operators in superclasses or parent classes.  If your superclass has data members, create a *protected* method that assigns the members of the superclass.  Don't infer anything about the child classes.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for taking the time to write me a clear answer. I appreciate your points. In my defence, the idea is that the assignment operator would simply query the subclass for a pointer to it's data, and a size; then write these data, byte by byte to an EEPROM. Does that make sense?

Comment: I work on embedded systems and I don't see any connection between the Timer and the EEPROM.  If you want to use a class to model an EEPROM, treat it as an array of `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`.  The issue is that many different types of data can be stored in EEPROM and making it a container means that you have to deal with multiple data types, which is a pain in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear.

```
 prog.cpp:24:74: error: passing 'const iContainer' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     void operator= (const iContainer &T) {   this->deSerialize(T.getData()); };
```

`getData` is a non-const function, you are not allowed to call it for T which is a const   reference. This has nothing to do with assignment.

There are many ways to make this work:

- don't call the useless `getData()` on a const reference
- provide a const overload for `getData()`
- provide a dedicated const notification callback
- ditch assignment altogether (it's a really bad idea in a polymorphic class hierarchy anyway)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it to compile - I need to learn more about the semantics of "const". I understand this is a contrived example.

#include 
    #include

```
class   iContainer  {
public:
    virtual         const int       size() const = 0;
    virtual         const uint8_t * getData() const  = 0;
    void    operator=(const iContainer &iC) { saveToEEPROM(iC.getData(), iC.size()); }

private:
    void    saveToEEPROM(const uint8_t *pData, int size) {
        // Save the data to EEPROM. 
    }
};


class Timer : public iContainer {
public:
    Timer()  {
        pData.myData = 0;
    };
    Timer(uint8_t startHour) {
        pData.myData = startHour;
    }
    virtual const int size()  { return sizeof(pData); }
    virtual const uint8_t *getData()  { return (const uint8_t *)&pData; };
private:
    struct {
        uint8_t myData;
    }   pData;
};
```